# What’s the difference between Domain Service and Infrastructure Service in NLayerd architecture?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, application-dependency

Also How do you distinguish between a Domain Command and Domain Service?

Answer (score 0):

A domain service is a service that services objects strictly related to the domain and operates on objects related to the domain - that deal with modelling the business / problem.

Infrastructure services deal with infrastructure, so services that support and build around domain services. A good example of this would be a repository. A repository is infrastructural because its role is to serve the domain, serve domain objects.

Domain = entities & associated behaviours.